# How to find top users by tag?

Tags: support, tags, top-users

How can I find the top users for a specific tag? For example, Java on Stack Overflow. I want to filter the "Users" tab by Java the tag.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check this (when hovering with the mouse over a tag)

> [image]

The last line of the popup shows the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers)

Or you can enter this url `https://stackoverflow.com/tags/<tag_name>/topusers`

For example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers

Comment: There is no longer a "Top Users" link displayed when hovering over a tag.  I'm not sure when it was changed.  The link still works.  Currently, 1/31/19, you need to first click on the tag, and then look for a "Top Users" link.

Comment: @AlanWells it was changed when they changed the design of the popup to something more "solid", so they also removed some useful links and features, because, well, why not. Which is super annoying. (The "subscribe" was super useful.)

Answer (score 7):

You can hover over the tag, which opens the mouseover thingy. Bottom Right Option is Top Users.

Alternately, in the queue for questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)) you have a link called Top Users - nestled between Improve Tag Wiki and Synonyms.

Comment: There is no longer a "Top Users" link displayed when hovering over a tag. I'm not sure when it was changed. You can still first navigate to the category tag, and then look for a "Top Users" link.

Answer (score 4):

Both the other answers mention hovering over a tag to get a link to the top users of that tag. Those links were visible in the old UI, but are no longer there.

To get to the top user ranking for a tag:

- Visit the page of the tag in question, either by clicking on it or navigating to /questions/tagged/example
- Click the top users link, found above the list of questions:
  [image]
- View the overview of top users for your desired tag:
  [image]

Alternatively you can navigate directly to [/tags/example/topusers](/tags/discussion/topusers)